# How can we get GitHub login name from firebase useAuthState?

Tags: reactjs, github, github-api

I'm created github login from firebase and I want to GitHub login name in different component.i use useAuthState but their is not login name only username present.please help me how can i get.

Comment: I guess, you need to first set the name as custom claims in the user when they register.

Comment: How can I set it custom

Comment: from any server. do an API call from client, send the details and from server use Admin SDK to set it.

Comment: Okk , Thank you.but I don't know how? can you provide some code an more explanation?

Comment: sure, which project are you in plain react, next.js?

Comment: but have you tried accessing the `displayName` property? https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#displayname

Comment: what do you get?